# xpath text within a span within text within a div

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying desperately to extract text from within a span which is within text which is within a div (underlined in the image)

[image: sample code]

This is the relevant part of the code ...

```
<div id="groupBlock3">
  <div class="groupBlockTitle">
    ::before
    "
                      ALL TEACHERES ("
    <span class="activeTeachers">12</span>
    " ACTIVE, "
    <span class="archivedTeachers">1</span>
    " ARCHIVED)
                    "
    <div>...</div>
    <div>+ enroll a teacher</div>
  </div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

I can retrieve the text from within the first div with this ...

```
"normalize-space(//div[@id='groupBlock3']/div[1])"
```

... which gives me ...

```
'ALL TEACHERES ( ACTIVE, ARCHIVED) + enroll a teacher'
```

... but, try as I might I cannot get the text from within the first or second span - it just returns a null string. Please help me!!

Comment: Did you try getting the xpath with your browser developer tools? https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=get+xpath+from+chrome&ia=web

Comment: I did, but it does the same - this is what dev tools tells me ... ```//*[@id="groupBlock3"]/div[1]/span[1]``` ... and it gives me the span element reference but then when I add ```/text()``` after it, nothing; empty list.

Comment: not sure whether this is something to do with ```::before```?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these XPath-1.0 expressions:

```
normalize-space(//div[@id='groupBlock3']/div[1]/span[1]/text())
```

which results in `12`, or, for the second `span`

```
normalize-space(//div[@id='groupBlock3']/div[1]/span[2]/text())
```

which results in `1`.

---

But if you want all text of the first `div`, use this expression

```
normalize-space(string(//div[@id='groupBlock3']/div[1]))
```

which gives you the result

> ::before " ALL TEACHERES (" 12 " ACTIVE, " 1 " ARCHIVED) " ...+ enroll a teacher

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work ... I wonder whether it might be something to do with the rest of the (very long) webpage that I can't share publicly ...

Comment: Maybe the HTML is generated/loaded dynamically via JavaScript.

Comment: That is a possibility :(

Comment: Yes - this is exactly the case - there is more javascript in the page than HTML which generates all the content dynamically - I assume you can't access js variable values using xpath?

Comment: I don't know how. You somehow have to access the fully loaded page (in the browser!?), _then_ you can use the XPath.

Comment: The JS counts the active teachers and students from a dynamic list and then fills in the total in the span :(